# How to properly use a custom service account with Firebase and Google Cloud Platform together

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I have a Firebase project set up and working now using a Firebase-generated service account (project settings > service accounts > generate new private key)

In my Firebase code, I initialize with the SA JSON file like so:

```js
import {initializeApp, cert} from 'firebase-admin/app'
initializeApp({
    credential: cert(require('../projectname-firebase-adminsdk-XXX-XXX.json')),
    storageBucket: 'project.appspot.com',
})
```

My issue now is arising while trying to implement Firebase enqueue functions using `onTaskDispatched` with cloud tasks. I've followed the example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions?gen=2nd). However, the iam permissions they say to give do not work as expected. First it gave me an error saying I needed the `cloudtasks.tasks.create` principal. So, I added the cloud tasks enqueuer role to the Firebase SA. Once that propagated it now says I need `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs`. This is where I am stumped. I can't figure out how to assign that principal.

Along with this, I have found a lot of mixed reviews on whether or not I should even be using a separate service account. Most say that I should let the environment use default credentials (not set a SA at all), and some say that it is good practice to have separate ones. There is not a lot of documentation on this specifically for Firebase with other Google services integrated. I'm hoping for a little guidance and insight on the best practices or at least how to get this working.

**Edit 1**

Just to add, this is how I implemented the `getFunctionUrl` function from the example:

```js
import {GoogleAuth} from 'google-auth-library'

export async function getFunctionUrl(
    name: string,
    location = 'us-central1'
) {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    })
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId()
    const url = "https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2beta/" +
        `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}/functions/${name}`

    const client = await auth.getClient()
    const res = await client.request({url})
    // @ts-ignore
    const uri = res.data?.serviceConfig?.uri
    if (!uri) {
        throw new Error(`Unable to retrieve uri for function at ${url}`)
    }
    return uri
}
```

This seems... wrong? I'm not sure if initializing Firebase using a SA will register with this package? Is this attempting to use default credentials? To test this I set my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path of my SA JSON and re-deployed to no effect.

**Edit 2**

I managed to figure out what it wanted for the actas principal. Solved this by assigning the service account user role to the SA. Everything is working now as expected. However, my question still stands on best practices involving multiple service accounts as opposed to the default.

Comment: When a Google service (Cloud Tasks) is configured with its own service account, you must have permission to use that service account. This is to prevent lower privilege code from calling another service that has different permissions. The `actAs` grants that permission. Think of it this way. Your company writes checks to purchase items. You do not have permission to write checks, but Sally in accounting does. Your boss tells Sally that you can request checks (the actAs permission) and she acts on your behalf to write a check.

Comment: This makes sense, but I still don't understand how initializing Firebase using my custom SA (aka the Firebase generated one) also tells google-auth-library to use it?

Comment: Do you mean by your code in `getFunctionUrl`? That code is using ADC (Application Default Credentials). ADC searches for credentials. Where is that code running? If a compute service such as Functions, then it is probably fetching credentials from the metadata service which are derived from the Function's attached service account. More details are required for me to know for sure.

Comment: I do not specialize in Firebase. I do not know if there is an interplay between `initializeApp` and the Google SDK clients.

Comment: I understand. Yes, I was talking about `getFunctionUrl`. More specifically, the `GoogleAuth` class. I'm not even sure if it is using the same service account as FB `initializeApp`, as I am not sure if it needs more principals than the default SA has to fetch the project ID. The code is running in a privileged environment -- a Firebase function which is just Google Cloud Run.

Comment: I don't understand your term `privileged environment`. Cloud Run is not a privileged environment. If your code is running in Cloud Run, then it is using the metadata service which is creating credentials from the attached Cloud Run service account.